# Zend select issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am having an issue with zend database table library;

Sorry, I got fixed the previous issue, but got another one at the function

`Message: Method "fetchAll" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()`

Here is the script I am using

```
 //setIntegrityCheck to false to allow joins
        $roomModel = new self();

        $select = $roomModel->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                ->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE);

        //performs join aliasing table room_type to t
        $select->join(array('t' => 'room_types'), 't.room_type_id = room.room_type_id AND num_beds> '.$number_beds);
        ////performs join aliasing table room_status to s
        $select->join(array('s' => 'room_statuses'), 's.room_status_id = room.room_status_id');

        $select->join(array('chin' => 'checkin'), 'chin.checkin_date IS NOT BETWEEN `'.$checkin.'` AND `'.$checkout.'`');

        $select->join(array('chout' => 'checkout'), 'chout.checkout_date IS NOT BETWEEN `'.$checkin.'` AND `'.$checkout.'`');

        $result = $this->fetchAll($select);

        return $result;
```

Comment: What is `$this` in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try $roomModel instead of $this